# Change Group widget title color in SWT

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an SWT window wherein there is Group widget in which i placed couple of other widgets,i set the title of group & its working fine. The group title color is blue always(in my case i am not sure) and that doesn't sync up with other children inside group.So i wonder if there is a way to change the group *title text* color and font if there is a way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy to change font of group, check this snippet (used snippet from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Demonstratesgroups.htm))

```
//Send questions, comments, bug reports, etc. to the authors:

//Rob Warner (rwarner@interspatial.com)
//Robert Harris (rbrt_harris@yahoo.com)

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

/**
 * This class demonstrates groups
 */
public class GroupExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    // Create the first group
    Group group1 = new Group(shell, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
    group1.setText("Who's your favorite?");
    group1.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    group1.setFont(new Font(display, "Consolas", 10, SWT.BOLD));
    new Button(group1, SWT.RADIO).setText("John");
    new Button(group1, SWT.RADIO).setText("Paul");
    new Button(group1, SWT.RADIO).setText("George");
    new Button(group1, SWT.RADIO).setText("Ringo");

    // Create the second group
    Group group2 = new Group(shell, SWT.NO_RADIO_GROUP);
    group2.setText("Who's your favorite?");
    group2.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    group2.setForeground(new Color(display, new RGB(255, 0, 0)));
    new Button(group2, SWT.RADIO).setText("Barry");
    new Button(group2, SWT.RADIO).setText("Robin");
    new Button(group2, SWT.RADIO).setText("Maurice");

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

It provides this behavior on W7

[image: font change on group in W7]

But as you can see, change of color by `setForeground(Color c)` doesn't change a thing, when I search for additional info I found bug report on SWT bugzilla [The color of the title of the group control cannot be changed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300121). It's windows platform dependent bug.

Answer (score 1):

But you can try a Group without text + a Label widget, this maybe a solution if you just want a better GUI.